# What can cause "Out Of Memory Exception" after navigating through app?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, runtime-error

As I navigate through pages in my android app, the app crashes with the Out Of Memory Exception, it basically happens sometimes, I have tried with finish() method. Also, the images used in my app are of the relevant size, means no extra space occupied. Need a permanent solution to get rid of this Exception.

Comment: Sounds like your activities aren't releasing memory as they should and they build up over time. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a memory leak in your app.
Use an allocation tracker to see if any objects are growing over a period of time

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html